# Sometime the jQuery Datatable is working, sometimes it is not?

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I did a web (angular 5) page host locally, I used datatable(jquery)to add some extra feature(like sort, filter, search..etc) to my table on html. When I try it first, the datatable works as I expected, but when I reload the page, its ui changes too, then all the datatable function does not work anymore....it seems like it occurs randomly. So I clear all the cookie and disable the page from using cookie, but the result are still the same. I also tried to use console log to see if the  $('#myTable').DataTable(); gets run when I reload the page, it actually runs every time I reload the page. I don't know where this went wrong. Note: I am using localhost/3000 to redirect my page to the \books page. Here is my sample index file code:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>QnAlist</title>
  <base href="/">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

  <app-root></app-root>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
  });



</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is my books component html code :

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 style="text-align: center">QnA List</h1>




  <table  class="display" id = 'myTable' >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> Question </th>
        <th> Answer </th>
        <th> Date </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let book of books">
        <td>{{ book.question }}</td>
        <td>{{ book.answer }}</td>
        <td>{{ book.timestamp }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: are you seeing any exception in console?

Comment: No I didn't see any err..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out a way to work around it....I can't find the answer, so I just stop using the jquery table, and use the primeng datatable. It works as I expect.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the datatable name: **this.dataTable = $ ('# dtData').** The id **dtData** i assigned it in several html components, my solution was to name each data table of each component with its own name: dtDataPerson, dtDataEmployee, etc.